# Web Scraping Weather Data 400 error

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, python-requests, http-post

I have tried using get requests with params, post requests with and without json.dumps but I can not seem to get the right response from the webpage.

I want to get back a text file with all the weather data. My code, the data I 
want, and the headers for the post request using the inspect on chrome is 
attached.

Thank you for any help!

You can also reach the data by

- going to http://climod2.nrcc.cornell.edu
- click on daily data listing
- input dates from 6/1/18 to current date
- check csv instead of html
- then type NY City Central Park for the station selection which will return 
  search results with that station then click go.

  Below are the screenshots:

  1. [Attempt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZgLkz.jpg)
  2. Had to delete due to not being able to post more than 8 links.
  3. [Headers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/stCM8.jpg)
  4. [Desired data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oRDtP.jpg)
  5. [Response Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dOIPP.jpg)
     `

  from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
  from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
  import requests
  import datetime
  import json

  payload = {'method': 'POST','params':{"elems":[{"name":"maxt","add":"t"}, 
  {"name":"mint","add":"t"},{"name":"pcpn","add":"t"}, 
  {"name":"snow","add":"t"},{"name":"snwd","add":"t"}],"sId":"94728 
  1","sDate":"2018-06-01","eDate":"2018-06-28"},'output':'json'}

  parameters = {"elems":[{"name":"maxt","add":"t"},{"name":"mint","add":"t"}, 
  {"name":"pcpn","add":"t"},{"name":"snow","add":"t"}, 
  {"name":"snwd","add":"t"}],"sid":"94728 1","sDate":"2018-06- 
  01","eDate":"2018-06-28"}

  headers = {'Accept': 'application/json, text/javascript, */*; 
  q=0.01','Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF- 
  8','Origin': 'http://climod2.nrcc.cornell.edu','Referer':'http://climod2.nrcc.cornell.edu/elems=name&elems=add&elems=name&elems=add&elems=name&elems=add&elems=name&elems=add&elems=name&elems=add&sDate=2018-06-01&eDate=2018-06-28&meta=name&meta=state&meta=ll&meta=sids&bbox=-74.44262803978918&bbox=40.4207924883181&bbox=-73.4880821602','User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/67.0.3396.87 Safari/537.36'}

  dataurl='https://data.rcc-acis.org/StnData'

  r = requests.post(dataurl, data = json.dumps(payload), headers = headers)

  print(r.status_code)
  print(r.elapsed)
  print(r.json)
  print(r.text)`

Comment: post your code here instead of an image file.

Comment: Thank you! I couldn't figure out how to get the imports in the block though.

Comment: select the code and enter Ctrl + K, refer https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code if you need more help.

Answer (score 1):

You just have to set the payload right.

This will do the trick.

```
import requests
from pprint import pprint

url = "https://data.rcc-acis.org/StnMeta"

payload = {
    "output": "json",
    "params": {"elems":[{"name":"maxt","add":"t"},{"name":"mint","add":"t"},{"name":"pcpn","add":"t"},{"name":"snow","add":"t"},{"name":"snwd","add":"t"}],"sDate":"2018-06-01","eDate":"2018-06-29","meta":["name","state","ll","sids"],"bbox":[-74.44262803978918,40.4207924883181,-73.48808216021084,41.144936911681896]}
}
r = requests.post(url, json=payload)
data = r.json()
```

The object named data will now consist of  list of dicts for each place that has weather data. Each dict contain amongst other an sid, that you need to feed the endpoint that return the actual weather data.

Each dict will look like this:

```
{'ll': [-74.42259, 40.47282],
  'name': 'NEW BRUNSWICK 3 SE',
  'sids': ['286055 2', 'USC00286055 6', 'NBRN4 7'],
  'state': 'NJ'}
```

Assuming that you want to loop through all these and return the weather data for each you first need to grab the sid's and store them in a list

Some of them, tho, does not contain weather data. They will look like this:

```
"US1NJES0018 6"
```

... while those that has weather data does not have letters in them. This can be exploited with a regex to filter away all sid's with letters in them.

So append this to the code:

```
import re # the regex library
sids_list = []

is_garbage = re.compile('[a-zA-z]+') # will match everything with a letter in
meta = data['meta']
for m in meta:
    name = m['name']
    sid = m['sids'][0]
    if not is_garbage.search(sid):
        sids_list.append([name,sid])
```

Now that you have a list of sid's, all you need to do is use the right payload to the final endpoint, set the dates you want data for - and start a loop.

```
start_date = "2018-06-01"
end_date = "2018-07-01"
for name, sid in sids_list:
    print("------------- DATA FOR {} (sid: {}) -------------".format(name,sid))
    print()
    payload2 = {
        "params": {
            "elems":
            [
                {"name":"maxt","add":"t"},
                {"name":"mint","add":"t"},
                {"name":"pcpn","add":"t"},
                {"name":"snow","add":"t"},
                {"name":"snwd","add":"t"}
            ],
            "sid": sid,
            "sDate":start_date,
            "eDate":end_date},
        "output": "json"
    }

    weather_url = "https://data.rcc-acis.org/StnData"
    r = requests.post(weather_url, json=payload2)
    weather_data = r.json()['data']
    print("{:15}{:15}{:15}{:15}{:15}{:15}".format("Date", "MaxTemperature", "MinTemperature", "Precipitation", "Snowfall", "SnowDepth"))
    for Date, MaxTemperature, MinTemperature, Precipitation, Snowfall, SnowDepth in weather_data:
        print("{:15}{:15}{:15}{:15}{:15}{:15}".format(Date, MaxTemperature[0], MinTemperature[0], Precipitation[0], Snowfall[0], SnowDepth[0]))
    print()
```

Here I'm just printing the data to screen in a nicely formatted view. Hope this solves your issue. Cheers.

Comment: The code is now getting a response but I am unsure how to get the exact data I need now. Here is some of what it outputs. `{'meta': [{'state': 'NJ', 'sids': ['286055 2', 'USC00286055 6', 'NBRN4 7'], 'll': [-74.42259, 40.47282], 'name': 'NEW BRUNSWICK 3 SE'}, {'state': 'NJ', 'sids': ['14734 1', '286026 2', 'EWR 3', '72502 4', 'KEWR 5', 'USW00014734 6', 'EWR 7'], 'll': [-74.1694, 40.6825], 'name': 'NEWARK LIBERTY INTL AP'}]}` However I need the data from picture 5 that I just added in my post. Thank you so much for the help so far.

Comment: you just need to replicate the steps I did on the final endpoint as well. The first endpoint get's data about each area available to extract weather data from. I figured you should be able to use the same method on the last endpoint too. Alas... I've updated the answer to extract weather data too - and not just the metadata about each area that has weather data available...